# Swift GameCenter not behaving properly

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite

I have 2 problems I am experiencing with GameCenter.

1. If a player is not signed into GameCenter, after if gives you the alert saying you are not signed in, I am no longer able to click any buttons I have on my view.
2. If a player is signed into GameCenter, after accessing the Leaderboards, pressing “done” will not dismiss the leaderboard view.

Here is my code that relates to GameCenter:

GameViewController:

```
func authPlayer() { // Gets called in ViewDidLoad
    let localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {
        (view, error) in

        if view != nil {
            self.presentViewController(view!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else {
            print(GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated)
        }
    }
}
```

GameScene:

```
if gameCenterBtn.containsPoint(location) { // In touches began for touch in touches
            saveHighScore(highLevel)
            let viewController = self.view!.window?.rootViewController
            let gcvc = GKGameCenterViewController()
            viewController?.presentViewController(gcvc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

func saveHighScore(number : Int) {
    if GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated {
        let scoreReporter = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier: "myLeaderBoardID")

        scoreReporter.value = Int64(number)
        let scoreArray : [GKScore] = [scoreReporter]

        GKScore.reportScores(scoreArray, withCompletionHandler: nil)
    }
}

func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController) {
    gameCenterViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Any and all help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

1) Not sure this will help, but your login code is not quite correct. If there is no login view controller doesnt necessarily mean the player is signed in. You are also not handling the optional error. Try this instead.

```
 localPlayer.authenticateHandler = { [unowned self] (viewController, error) in // will handle login changes also
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        if let viewController = viewController {
            self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else if self.localPlayer.authenticated {
            print("Player authenticated")
        }
        else {
            print("Player not authenticated")

        }
    }
```

I am not sure why your gameViewCntroller will not respond. Are you not just loading the first SKScene in your gameViewController. 
Could you describe further, maybe with some code, of what does not work afterwards.

2) Its not dismissing the screen because you did not set the delegate.

You code where you are creating the Game Center viewController should look like this

```
 let viewController = self.view?.window?.rootViewController
 let gcvc = GKGameCenterViewController()
 gcvc.gameCenterDelegate = self // YOU FORGOT THIS LINE
 viewController?.presentViewController(gcvc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```